# Groovy's inconsistent destructuring / decomposition on lists?

Tags: groovy, closures, decomposition, destructuring

Positive Case: Can get into a list

```
groovy> println GroovySystem.version  
groovy> final data1 = [[99,2] , [100,4]] 
groovy> data1.collect{x,y->x+y} 

2.2.1
Result: [101, 104]
```

Negative Case: *Can not do the same*

```
groovy> println GroovySystem.version  
groovy> final data = [x:[99,2] , y:[100,4]] 
groovy> data.collect{key,  val-> 
groovy>    val.collect{x,y->x+y} 
groovy> }.flatten() 

2.2.1
Exception thrown

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: ConsoleScript80$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [99]
Possible solutions: doCall(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), findAll(), findAll(), isCase(java.lang.Object), isCase(java.lang.Object)
    at ConsoleScript80$_run_closure1.doCall(ConsoleScript80:5)
    at ConsoleScript80.run(ConsoleScript80:4)
```

Comment: In the second example, when collect is called on val, val is [99, 2]; the closure will get called first passing in 99, then again passing in 2. It doesn't make any sense to have two variables passed into the closure because at this point what collect is called on is a list of scalar values. Is there a reason to think this should work?

Comment: I am not pushing any arguments here, I just want to understand. 
e.g. this works
final v=1;
v.collect{it+1};
this could work too, but no
final l = [1,2];
l.collect{x,y->x+y};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is

```
data.collect { key, val -> val.with { x, y -> x + y } }
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe you want

```
data.values().collect{x,y->x+y}
```

Comment: OP's code iterates over `data`'s key-value pairs
The first key-value pair is `x:[99,2]`

Then iteration occurs on **the members of each value**.
The first member is `99`--but the closure provided takes two parameters--and so the exception is thrown.

If OP wishes to sum each pair of numbers then I'd suggest iterating over `data`'s values summing each pair as shown above.

Comment: An alternative is `data.collect { key,  val -> val.with { x, y -> x + y } }`

Comment: @tim_yates Could you put your comment as an answer?